# compiler backend for a functional language

Tags: compiler-construction, functional-programming, dynamic-typing

I have written an interpreter for a functional language, which I niw try to bootstrap using a compiler. The language has a dynamic type system and uses lists, numbers and strings. It also is functional and a function takes its argumenta as a list (like perls @_, or js arguments). Functions are first class and can be nested. Which language should I target with the compiler, btw. I think targetting a static typed imperative language, like C would be hard. The language should support dynamic typing and functional programming (js wouldnt be nice - the language should have a compiler itself, like common lisp)

Comment: Check out [QBE](http://c9x.me/compile/).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any special support from your target language. Dynamic dispatch can be resolved by using generic versions of your functions (but consider optimising it away when types can be safely inferred), e.g., for `a + b` you can generate a code like `generic_add(a, b)`, where `generic_add` is a function that selects a suitable implementation depending on runtime type information.

For the functional part, it's trivial to eliminate it using lambda lifting. For the latter you simply need to build lists of free and bound variables for each AST node: list of free variables is built from the leaves to the root, and a bound list is built in the opposite direction. For each lambda node you subtract free from bound, and build a new top-level function which takes both explicit lambda arguments and this difference (i.e., the captured variables).

Also, if you want to do optimisations or if your language is supposed to support continuations, consider using a CPS-transform.

Comment: Excelent answer! Thank you very much, can you call a specific language I should consider using? That would be extremely nice

Comment: Use any language which can provide you with the runtime features you want (you may or may not want a GC, for example, some specific libraries, whatever). If in doubt or there are no specific needs at all, feel free to use C, it's a common choice and this path is very well covered in multiple books and tutorials. You can also target LLVM IR directly.

Comment: Is there a like button on stackoverflow, I really want to press it :)

Comment: You can upvote and/or accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Targeting low-level languages like LLVM and C is fine as long as you are willing to implement dynamic dispatch, closures, etc. yourself.  However, since you mention JavaScript as a possible target (except for the lack of compilers, though even JS is JIT-compiled in major browsers nowadays), how about Scheme?  It is a dynamically typed, higher-order functional language and already has native-code compilers: http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-standards#implementations The only problem may be that it is too close to your source language and your compiler (or "translator", I might say) would be too easy perhaps.:-)

If you are willing to target C, a good starting point may be Marc Feeley's tutorial "The 90 minute Scheme to C compiler": http://churchturing.org/y/90-min-scc.pdf